# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION happens without upserting the field

Tags: validation-rule, bulk-api

I wrote a script to export the data to SFDC using the [bulk API 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/walkthrough_upload_multipart_data.htm)
I upserts a bunch of user ids which is an external id of the object. I was expecting it returns errors "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING:Required fields are missing" if the entry already exists, or upserting success if it doesn't. However I received this error:

```
`FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION:{Field f} can only be selected by an {Field f SDR}:Field_f__c`
```

My question is, I didn't include Field_f__c in my csv file, so I was not intend to updating it, why did I trigger a validation exception on this field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION** means that there is a validation rule defined in your org and the record you are updating does not meet this rule. When you update a record the entire record is checked against validation rules, even if you are not modifying those fields (unless you have something like `ISCHANGED()` in your validation rule).

You're getting the error because you are attempting to update a record that is in violation of a rule, most likely because the record was created before the rule existed.

Otherwise, the rule is simply coded incorrectly. If you can find the validation rule that is throwing the error and provide it, we might be able to help you adjust the rule so that it doesn't continue to fail.

Lastly, my company uses a generic admin user that is exempted from all validation rules when doing bulk imports to avoid errors like this. The validation could be updated to have an exclusion for your API user. Something like `NOT($User.Alias = 'BULKUSER')`

Comment: Thank you @gNerb. This provides me with quite much background info! I'll check the validation rule with the owner first.

Answer (score -2):

Its because of the default value.

Whenever you create a field you have to specify a default value. So if you create a record without specifying the value of a field(In your case Field_f__c ) then default value from Schema /Object definition gets copied on the record.  [image]

There would be validation rule, which prevents setting this default value when certain conditions are met. And thus your question.